# UIColor colour with image is not working below IOS 7

Tags: ios, uiimage, uitextview, uicolor

I have to set a color to text of UITextField. That colour text will be dynamic and its colour will be get from am Image of One colour(say white, hello, brown image). If i have to do statically then i can do by getting RGB of image. but the images are dynamic.

I am using below code to set the colour text of UItextview

```
_textView.textColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:Image];
```

This code is working fine in IOS7 but not working below IOS7

How we can fix this issue?

Comment: If the images are of one single colour, why don't you set the color from RGB values? Also, try naming your variable as "image", and not "Image". It might be messing with some reserved word, a class named Image or something.

Comment: i dnt want to use rgb value

Comment: See apexwill's answer below.  Post your code and someone will probably help you.

Answer (score 2):

The code is fine. `-[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:]` works well below iOS 7. There must be something elsewhere in your code causing the problem.

Comment: This should probably be a comment.